# Help for a Markov chain graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm trying to draw a Markov chain graph but I'm not able to do it properly, can someone help me?
The transition probabilities matrix is:

```
0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   \\ 
0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   \\ 
1/3 & 1/3 & 0   & 0   & 1/3 & 0   \\ 
0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 
0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 \\ 
0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   \\
```

Comment: there is a "2" in your matrix and there is a line that des not add up to 1. Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = stealth',
  auto,
  prob/.style = {inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize}
  ]
  \node[state] (a) {$a$};
  \node[state] (b) [above right=of a] {$b$};
  \node[state] (c) [below right=of b] {$c$};
  \node[state] (e) [right=of c] {$e$};
  \node[state] (d) [above right=of e] {$d$};
  \node[state] (f) [below right=of d] {$f$};
  \path[->] (a) edge node[prob]{$1/2$} (b)
                edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1/2$} (c)
            (b) edge[loop above] node[prob]{$1$} (b)
            (c) edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1/3$} (a)
                edge node[prob,swap]{$1/3$} (b)
                edge node[prob]{$1/3$} (e)
            (e) edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1/2$} (d)
                edge node[prob,swap]{$1/2$} (f)
            (d) edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1/2$} (e)
                edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1/2$} (f)
            (f) edge[bend left=10] node[prob]{$1$} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, you do this manually or is there some type of programm?

Comment: I do it manually, as it is more flexible, and once you know the commands, you can do all kinds of drawings. For graphs, there are also graphical programs that are able to export latex/tikz code, see e.g. https://tikzit.github.io/ or www.mathcha.io